# Why press Enter to run code when end=" " parameter is used inside the print() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("abc", end = "d")
```

After pressing the run button, there's an extra need of pressing the enter key to run the code.
Also, that outputs to:

```
> 
abcd> |
```

with `abcd` printed on the second line. (`|` is showing the cursor position after completion.)

On the other hand,

```
print("abc", end = "d")
print()
```

outputs to

```
abcd
> |
```

My question is why there's a need to press Enter to run the code when end=" " parameter is used inside the print() function?

Comment: Output is buffered until a newline is printed. Add the `flush=True` option to flush the buffer.